# ByteArrayOutputStream for shorts instead of bytes

Tags: java, short, bytearrayoutputstream

I have used the ByteArrayOutputStream which is very useful but for my needs the limits are too great (ie I am dealing with numbers in the range +-32,768)

Here is the code where I would use it:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream leftStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ByteArrayOutputStream rightStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

while (din.read(temp, 0, 4) != -1) {
    if (decodedFormat.getChannels() == 2) {
       leftStream.write(temp[1] * 256 + temp[0]);
       rightStream.write(temp[3] * 256 + temp[2]);
    }
}

byte[] left = leftStream.toByteArray();
byte[] right = rightStream.toByteArray();
```

However the ByteArrayInputStream does not allow for values over 127 or under 128. Is there an equivalent ShortArrayOutputStream that allows shorts? Or do I have to make one myself somehow?

Comment: Use a ByteBuffer and call ByteBuffer.getShort

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Use the DataOutputStream:

```
ByteArrayOuputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(bos);

dos.writeShort(val);
```

This works even on embedded java devices with low java version 1.3

To read in use:

`ByteArrayInputStream` and `DataInputStream` dis, and `dis.readShort()`:

```
...
byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();
ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);
short val = dis.readShort();
```

Comment: Thank you, if I write shorts with values larger than 128 then the toByteArray surely will not let those shorts through?

Comment: A short is 2byte in java: from -32767 to 32768 in java. so exactly what you write out, is read in. you have to read it in the same order your write it. If all are shorts then fine. You  can mix bytes with shorts and int, but to use the smae order when reading in.

Comment: Aha I understand, I will try to implement

Comment: Just write a unit test case, the you will easily see what you get in.

Answer (score 1):

What do you want to do?

**Write out short data to a byte array?**

Then wrap your byte array output stream with a DataOutputStream which has methods to writeShort(), writeInt() etc.  Warning. I think the endian of DataOutputStream is BIG endian so if you want to use little endian you either have to write it yourself or use the other option:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
DataOutputStream dataout = new DataOutputStream(byteOut)

dataout.writeShort(shortValue);
```

**Write a short[]**

the easiest is to create a ByteBuffer, then use the `asShortBuffer()` method to view it as a ShortBuffer.  the ShortBuffer has a `put(short)` and put(short[]);

If you want to write out the short data in Little endian, ByteBuffer has a method `asOrder(ByteOrder)` which can change the endian of the data it is reading or writing.

```
//NOTE length should be 2* num shorts since we allocate in bytes
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(length);

ShortBuffer shortBuf = buf.asShortBuffer();
shortBuf.put(shortValue);
shortBuf.put(shortArray);
```

getting data out from buffers is annoying.  There are optional `array()` methods but not all buffer impelmentations support them so you have to do the following:

```
//once all data written to buffer
shortBuf.flip();
short[] dataOut = new short[shortBuf.remaining()];
shortBuf.get(dataOut);
```

**Combination of both to use a ShortBuffer on an unknown input size**

If you don't know how many bytes you will write, and you don't have a reasonable, max length, then you may need to do a combination of both options.  First, use option #1 to dynamically grow a byte buffer by writing shorts to it.  Then convert the byte[] to a short[] with the ShortBuffer.

```
 ByteArrayOutputStream byteOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
DataOutputStream dataout = new DataOutputStream(byteOut)

dataout.writeShort(shortValue);
...

ShortBuffer buf =ByteBuffer.wrap(byteOut.toByteArray())
                           .asShortBuffer();

int length = buf.remaining();
short[] asShorts = new short[length];
buf.get(asShorts);
```

It's not pretty and uses 2x the memory since you make a copy of the array.

Comment: Could you post an example of how to use the second option?

Comment: This is not the easisest option. But on PCs much faster than the dataOutputStream solution. Little and big endian was never a point in his question

Comment: @dkatzel Thanks for example, but the reason I am using the stream is because I don't know how many bytes I would be using before, so how can I calculate length?

Comment: @Cobbles added more code to explain one way to do it.

Comment: i will not do it, but for this overcomplicated solution i would re-add a -1. But it's a very fast solution when maximum performance at higher development costs is needed.

Comment: @AlexWien I agree it's ugly and if I was OP, I might just end up writing my own version of ShortArrayInputStream(). But this is easier than that.

Comment: Just use the DataInputStream I use it for years, see below my answer. I do all serialisation with that, the ByteBuffer solution is faster if th edevcie has a DMA access (or disc operations). Our emebedded devcies have not, they use java 1.5, but still MemorsyMapped and ByteBuffer was no advantage, ( bit slower) on PCs they were much faster.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the `ByteArrayOutputStream` into `DataOutputStream`:

```java
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream);

dataOutputStream.writeShort(someShortValue);
```

Comment: How can one then retrieve the short[] array from that stream? Like some `toShortArray()` method?

Comment: @Cobbles with readShort() of course, but from an DataInputStream()

Comment: @Cobbles you will have `DataInputStream` on the other side.

Comment: @AlexWien,partlov How does one get an InputStream from the dataOutputStream?

Comment: I am not sure what is you use case. If you are transferring an array through network you will have input stream.

Comment: new DataInputStream(new byteArrayInputStream(bos.getBytes()));

Answer (score -1):

Create a ObjectOutputStream. This has a writeShort (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#writeShort(int)) method.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
oos.writeShort(123);
...
```

Comment: Object OutputStream is overkill since that is supposed to be used to serialize objects not write out primitive arrays

Comment: and it uses a huge amount of storage, and is slow like hell.